# Reflection.Emit code calls "base." instead of "this." on Boolean field

Tags: c#, reflection, clr, reflection.emit, il

I have the following class A.

```
public class A
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

I need to emit a dynamic proxy using Reflection.Emit to override Equals.

```
// This class must be generated by Reflection.Emit.
public class AProxy : A
{
    private bool equalsHasBeenCalled;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (this.equalsHasBeenCalled)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        this.equalsHasBeenCalled = true;

        return CaseInsensitiveComparer.Equals(this, obj); // Demo.
    }
}
```

However, the actual generated code (viewed with Reflector) is:

```
public class AProxy : A
{
    private bool equalsHasBeenCalled;

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (base.equalsHasBeenCalled)
        {
            return base.Equals(obj);
        }

        base.equalsHasBeenCalled = true;

        return CaseInsensitiveComparer.Equals(this, obj);
    }
}
```

..which of course throws a System.FieldAccessException (since no such member exists). The correct is to call *this.equalsHasBeenCalled* (not base.equalsHasBeenCalled).

I am using the Reflection.Emit add-in for Reflector to generate the code (field1 is the FieldInfo for the "equalsHasBeenCalled" field):

```
        // Writing body
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);

        // I suspect it has to be around here.
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldfld, field1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ceq);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue_S, label25);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Nop);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method2);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, label42);
        gen.MarkLabel(label25);

        // ..and probably here also?
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stfld, field1);

        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_1);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Call, method3);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Br_S, label42);
        gen.MarkLabel(label42);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
        gen.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
```

Comment: So how do you see this output? Sounds like broken decompiler...

Comment: Why not show us your own code for Reflection.Emit?

Comment: Why dont you write what you need in C#, decompile to IL and see how it's set up?
Also, if you need to do any more of things like this in your project, I suggest you look into Castle DynamicProxy.

Comment: @leppie That is all I have. I think I need to dig into IL manually as Nikola suggested..

Comment: Something wrong with the FieldInfo.  Did you get it from TypeBuilder.DefineField?  Show that snippet.

Comment: Then i'll add it as answer :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why dont you write what you need in C#, decompile to IL and see how it's set up? Also, if you need to do any more of things like this in your project, I suggest you look into Castle DynamicProxy.

Comment: That was the best thing to do. After looking at generated IL I found that the generated Reflection.Emit code was correct. It was just that I had supplied a FieldInfo for "field1" while I had to supply an instance of a FieldBuilder for "field1". Everything works. Looking at IL was enlightening!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the this keyword is triggering a bug in your Reflection.Emit add-in to make it generate the wrong code.  Try removing it as it is not really doing anything, there is no other `equalsHasBeenCalled` you need to disambiguate using the this keyword.

Comment: Huh, `this` and `base` does not exist in IL.

Comment: @leppie I was assuming from his description he was compiling the code in his first example to IL and then using the add in to to generate the reflection.emit code.

Comment: @BenRobinson Yes, probably.. :(